# Issue with Gradle and minifyEnabled Error :app:transformClassesAndResourcesWithProguardForRelease'

Tags: android, gradle

I have gotten the following error when enabling minify for my release.

> Error:Execution failed for task
>   ':app:transformClassesAndResourcesWithProguardForRelease'.

I did research on this and the error has to do with my gradle versions not all matching.

What am I missing here so I can get rid of the error?

In my project gradle, I have the following:

```
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.1'
    classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.0.1'
}
```

In my app gradle I have:

```
android {
    useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy'
    compileSdkVersion 26
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "PACKAGE_NAME"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 26
        versionCode 30
        versionName "1.0.30"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        manifestPlaceholders = [
                onesignal_app_id               : 'XXX',
                onesignal_google_project_number: 'XXX'
        ]
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    buildToolsVersion '26.0.2'
}
```

I am also using:

```
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-4.1-all.zip
```

Comment: Post the build message please

Answer (score 0):

**Add in your `proguard-rules.pro` the lines below. It will solve the problems:**

```
-dontwarn org.apache.http.**
-dontwarn org.apache.commons.**
```